# Python parse configuration tokens from log4j in order to parse logs

Tags: python, parsing, logging, log4j

I want to parse a log4j *configuration* in order to know how to parse a given log.

Requirements: python 2.6+, no custom c modules (unless absolutely required).

For example:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p{length=5} [%t] %c:%L %message%n
```

or

```
%d{ISO8601} %-5p{length=5} ((%t) %c:%L) %message%n
```

As a reference, the pattern layout is described here:

[Pattern Layouts for log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Patterns)

Initially, I was going to customize it for each log pattern, as an example using re:

```
log1 = re.compile(r'([\d-]{10}) ([\d:.]{12}) {1}([A-Z]{0,}) \[(catalina-exec-[0-9]{2})\]{0,} (.*)\n')
```

**Note**: I realize that this is not a very comprehensive use of re, nor is it an optimized regular expression. It was testing only.

I initially started using [parsimonious](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsimonious) like so (very early stage):

```
    from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
    grammar = Grammar(
        r"""
        category = "%c"
        category_precise = category optional_open number optional_close
        timedate = '%d'
        timedate_absolute = timedate optional_open timedate_abstext optional_close
        timedate_iso = timedate optional_open timedate_isotext optional_close
        timedate_date = timedate optional_open timedate_date optional_close
        timedate_era = "G"
        timedate_year_two_digit = ~"y{2}"
        timedate_year_number = ~"(?:y{1}|y{3,}"            
        timedate_month = "MM"
        timedate_minute = "mm"
        """
```

Effectively, I am wondering if I am going about it the wrong way? It almost seems like I am using a PEG parser in the wrong way, in fact the more I look at it, I think I am.

I don't need full code, just a good concept, a start, an idea, or a good place to start reading.

In the end, I want to be able to review a log format, and for lack of better words "convert the log4j2 pattern into a regular expression"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: By "Python 2.6+" do you mean "all Python versions from 2.6 onwards" or "any Python version from 2.6 onwards" or "Python 2.6 and/or 2.7" or something else?

Comment: Preferably it working from Python 2.6-3.6.x as of the time of this writing, for instance, CentOS/RHEL 6 comes with Python 2.6, and despite even Python 2.7 approaching EOL, RHEL/CentOS 6 is valid until 2020 for primary update, and 2024 for maintenance, since the project I am starting is targeting a corporate env, ideally it will work across.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Plex 2.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plex/). I have found it easy to write the code that would identify tokens such as ISO8601, %d, %t, etc, from the configuration file. Then, as you will discern from the documentation, I expect that you will be able to write regex code to be returned by Plex that parses the log file itself.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out! I am planning on writing a regex for each token so I can not only split the log via regex, but also break down dates and times so python can work with the data. Once complete I will open source it.

Comment: I've tried looking @ plex 2.0, although it looks like quite the amazing product, although I am having the same trouble with plex that I did prior, my initial use-case [read %d == date, %d{yyyy-mm-dd ...} is date, in this format] I can't seem to find any examples, it seems easier for me to parse the actual log since I am able to setup the regular expressions from looking at the log, but I can't seem to get %d and %d{whatever} working.  I can using regex named groups, but I was hoping to use a lexer for everything.

Comment: Amend your question to provide a specific configuration line and a specific log line or collection of log lines that match that configuration and I will try to write a lexer using Plex.